Should tag [btc-trading-corp] be removed
I noticed a recent question used the tag [btc-trading-corp]
There are currently seven questions with this tag. It seems to have started with this 2013 question about a now-defunct company BTC Trading Corp.

IMPORTANT NOTICE TO ALL EX BTC-TC TRADERS
BTC Trading Corp has partnered with TxQuick to relaunch the website as a crypto to crypto blockchain trading platform. The demo site is now live. Feel free to sign up and give it a spin.

All the other uses seem, from a superficial glance, to be errors where perhaps the OP selected any tag that came up when they typed "trading".
I suggest this tag be removed.
I would have suggested replacing current uses with [trading] - but I'm not sure [trading] is a particularly useful tag.

I've edited the tags of all seven questions that were previously tagged with btc-trading-corp to remove it. 
I would further agree that trading is a fairly broad tag. It and a few of its friends such as e.g. trade and market should be revisited at some point. ;)
